# Convert an HTML table to pdf, arabic not supported,also only few columns are shown

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html-table

I am trying to convert an HTML table with dynamic data which might also include Arabic into a PDF.

I am using JSPDF. However only the first few columns are shown in the PDF.

I have also tried to use CSV but couldn't find a way to get it into a tabular form.

My questions:

1. How do I get to show all my HTML table columns in the PDF using JSPDF, and provide support for Arabic?
2. Is there a way to email this file as an attachment to known user?

Comment: hi bro, did you find any solution?